# Asus Zenbook - Nvidia driver issue - mx150

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I searched for hours and tried several solutions but I'm still stuck and I'm not sure to have everything working properly.

The situation is the following:

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux rocco 5.4.0-28-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 17:40:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ubuntu 20.04

The driver seems installed correctly

Output of `lsmod | grep nvidia`:

```
nvidia_uvm            966656  0
nvidia_drm             45056  0
nvidia_modeset       1114112  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              20430848  2 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        184320  2 nvidia_drm,i915
ipmi_msghandler       106496  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
drm                   491520  13 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
```

Output of `prime-select query`:

```
nvidia
```

Output of `sudo lshw -c display`:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:127 memory:ed000000-edffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP108M [GeForce MX150]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:ef000000-ef07ffff
```

Output of `inxi -Fxx`:

```
Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:5917 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX150] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia v: 440.64 bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1d10 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: none compositor: gnome-shell resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1680x1050~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.4 direct render: Yes
```

Output of `lspci -v | grep 3D`:

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
    Memory at ee000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
```

Output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
Thu May  7 23:18:08 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64       Driver Version: 440.64       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX150       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   45C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

BUT:

Output of `more /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf`:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "AMDgpu"
    MatchDriver "amdgpu"
    Driver "amdgpu"
EndSection
```

Output of `nvidia-settings`:

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:5784): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 23:19:26.837: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

[image: NVIDIA X Server Settings]

I think I should have seen a list of options in this panel.

**optirun --status** does not say nothing
**chrome://gpu** is reporting only my Intel UHD Graphics 620

If I launch **glxgears** I cannot see any processes on nvidia-smi

At the end I'm not sure if I'm using the nvidia drivers or not.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Goto software & updates then the additional drivers tab
Under your GPU make sure you select the one that says proprietary, tested and hit apply changes
[image: nvidia_driver]

Comment: Sure, I installed the driver using the method you suggested and the result is my initial question :)

Comment: Therefore you have the nvidia drivers installed if you want to double check you can go to settings>details>about and see what it says under graphics

Comment: It says  "[GeForce MX150] / llvmpipe" I guess is using llvmpipe